# mysql date literal using the date keyword

Tags: mysql, date

MySql manual [states](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

***As a number in either YYYYMMDD or YYMMDD format, provided that the number makes sense***

with regard to using temporal literals in the form: 830905 would be equivalent to 1983-09-05.

Then why doesn't this code work?:

```
SELECT DATE 830905;
```

And only the string version work?:

```
SELECT DATE '890905';
```

The manual states that you can use either a  string or a number.

Comment: Did you see the sample code. The type keyword is in the sample code above and it takes into consideration the option to use a string.

Comment: `DATE 'xxxxx'` is a standard SQL (ANSII) format, which supports only a string literal. If you want to use a number, use `DATE( number )` like this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/26987